# How to check list.contains in jsp using struts 2 tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I need to show a series of check boxes and if a condition is succeeded, I need to check them. Below is my code. I have regions which is a hashmap and SelectedRegions which is an array list. I am iterating over my regions map, and displaying checkboxes with text next to it as the value from my regions map. Now, while iterating, if the value of regions map is available in the array list, I need to make the check box checked. else Un checked. I tried like the one shown below. But its not working.

```xml
<s:iterator value="regions">
    <li>
        <div class="listClass">
            <s:if test="#regions.value==selectedRegions.value">
                <input type="checkbox" id='myTheater' checked="checked" name="theaterCheckBox" class="theaterCheckBox" />
                <s:property value="value" />
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <input type="checkbox" id='myTheater' name="theaterCheckBox" class="theaterCheckBox" />
                <s:property value="value" />
            </s:else>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" id="allFeatured" class="featuredCheckBox" />
        </div>
    </li>
</s:iterator>
```

Some how, the if condition that I am using is not working. Could you please 
let me know how to attain this?

Comment: Any reason you're not using struts2 tags for your inputs? Also, I haven't used struts2, but shouldn't it be `#{condition}` rather than `#condition`?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Definitely not `#{...}`. user1321648: How would you do this in class?

Comment: I am not using struts tags as it is not allowing me to do customization. I need to display a drop down with two checkboxes side by side. I cant attain this by using struts 2 input tags.

Comment: I also tried using the condition-  <s:if test="#regions.value in selectedRegions"> But it didnt work.

Comment: @aleksandr M: In my class I would say for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(myList.contains(entry.getValue()))
    // ...
}

Comment: @user1321648: Now try it on JSP.

Comment: I cant use sciptlets. Need to use struts tags as per our coding standards

Comment: @user1321648: I didn't mean to use scriplets. :) Just use if part with correct variable names in JSP in `<s:if>` tag.

Comment: The action bean is made for presenting your data in JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really many ways to do this. You should also check out the `<s:checkbox/>` and `<s:checkboxlist/>` tags;

Also note that to follow DRY, you could put the `<s:if>` around the `checked="checked"` part only, since all the rest is the same.

Keeping it simple, with your code as-is, one way consists in using OGNL's `in` (*contains*) and OGNL's `{}` (*list projection*) like follows:

```xml
<s:iterator value="regions">
    <li>
        <div class="listClass">

            <input type = "checkbox" 
                     id = "myTheater" 
<s:if test="%{value in selectedRegions.{value}}">
                checked = "checked"
</s:if>
                   name = "theaterCheckBox" 
                  class = "theaterCheckBox" />

            <s:property value="value" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" id="allFeatured" class="featuredCheckBox" />
        </div>
    </li>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea Ligios. It worked like a charm. I used this- <s:if test="%{value in selectedRegions}">